# PHP how to simulate SIGPIPE?

Tags: php, sigpipe

My environment:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
PHP 7.2.2 ZTS no-debug

I have a big application where sometimes `Broken pipe` error is happening. 
I want to handle it but for this I need to simulate this error for development. How can I do that ?

I have tried:

```
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGPIPE);
while(1) {
    sleep(5);
}
```

Also:

```
sudo kill -13 pid
```

But script keep working.

Expected result:

```
Thread 1 "php" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
```

and script should get stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**signal_example.php:**

```
pcntl_async_signals(true);

pcntl_signal(SIGPIPE, function (int $signo) {
    echo 'Process ' . posix_getpid() . ' "php" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.';
    exit;
});

while (1) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

kill -13 990:

```
artemev@Vitaly-PC:~/project/example$ php signal_example.php 
Process 990 "php" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
```